# Android Instant Apps Samples Not Pulling GitHub Repository

Tags: android-studio, android-instant-apps

When I try to create/import a sample and use Instant apps, the code is not pulled from GitHub repository. Any thoughts?
In addition, I have also tested the Hello World Sample (Java) and the GitHub Repository associated page does not exist.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, looks like some of these links are broken, or the the sample project itself is incomplete.

For example, when you click through `Browse source in Github` for that *[Hello World (Java)](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/hello-java)*, you'll get a **404**, and the *[Kotlin](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/hello-kotlin)* one seems to be missing all its files.

Looks like [googlesamples/android-instant-apps](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps) is going through some renovations. This is likely due to the Instant Apps model [being shifted over to the App Bundle / Dynamic Features model](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/04/google-play-instant-feature-plugin.html). So for the time being, it's probably just better to just browse it on Github, download, unzip, then open with Android Studio, instead of trying to open it directly from studio.